# how can i reset te score variable after every loop so they dont add up?

Tags: python

so i have run this code 3 times as there is 3 loops, however after every loop, the score variable seems to add itself on from the previous loop for e.g 1st loop (first user) gets a score of 2, then 2nd user get 4 and the last user gets 6. when i want to individually output all 3 users scores seperately, the code just adds on the scores. therefore this results in false scores. any solution to fix the score variable to reset every loop but still be attached to the 'schooldata[x]['score']' (x being the user number for e.g user 2 score would be 'schooldata[1]['score']) and which this outputs 3 seperate scores, specific to each user.

```
score = 0
schooldata = []
for x in range (0,3):
    quiz = dict()
    print ("Enter your name")
    quiz['name'] = input()
    print ("what class")
    quiz['class_code'] = input()

    print("1. 9+10=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 19:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong") 
    print("2. 16+40=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)
    if answer == 56:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("3. 5+21=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer) 
    if answer == 26:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("4. 5-6=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)
    if answer == -1:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")

    print("5. 21-9=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 12:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")


    print("6. 12-11=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 1:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")



    print("7. 5*6=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 30:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")



    print("8. 1*8=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 8:
        print("correct")

        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")


    print("9. 4*6=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 24:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1

    else:
        print("wrong")



    print("10. 9*10=")
    answer = input()
    answer = int(answer)

    if answer == 90:
        print("correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("wrong")
    quiz['score'] = score
    schooldata.append(quiz)

user1=("name - ", schooldata[0]['name'],", user score - ", schooldata[0]['score'],", class number - ", schooldata[0]['class_code'])
print ("if you want student 1's results and information, please type 'user[0][0]'")
user = input()
if user == "user1":
    print ("name - ", schooldata[0]['name'],", user score - ", schooldata[0]['score'],", class number - ", schooldata[0]['class_code'])
```

Comment: why not just put `score=0` inside the for loop

Comment: oh yeah, stupid of me, thanks for spotting that